# pass native android Webview object in kony FFI

Tags: ffi, temenos-quantum

I have created pdf WebView library in native android.In Static method,have to pass Webiew object and String.let me know how to pass webview object in kony FFI.

Below am adding static method library code:

```
public static void pdfGeneration(WebView webView,String name){

    webView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    webView.layout(0, 0, webView.getMeasuredWidth(),
            webView.getMeasuredHeight());
    webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.buildDrawingCache();

    // create a new document
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

    // crate a page description
    PageInfo pageInfo = new PageInfo.Builder(webView.getMeasuredWidth(), webView.getMeasuredHeight(), 1).create();

    // start a page
    Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

    // draw something on the page
    webView.draw(page.getCanvas());

    // finish the page
    document.finishPage(page);


    try {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        OutputStream fOut = null;
        File file = new File(path, "/"+name+".pdf");
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        document.writeTo(fOut);
        // close the document
        document.close();
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}`
```